# Dividing prices by 3

Tags: c#, math, numbers

For accounting program I need to divide a price by 3 so it can be shared over 3 months

For example 9€

- 3€ first month
- 3€ second month
- 3€ third month

Now this would be price/3

But what if the number is 10?

- 3,33€ first month
- 3,33€ second month
- 3,33€ last month

3,33€*3 =€9.99

One cent has gone missing.
How can I make it so the ouput would become 3,33€ , 3,33€ , 3,34€?

Comment: What is the preferred output for dividing $0.05? Would it be (0.01, 0.01, 0.03), or (0.01, 0.02, 0.02)?

Comment: Just add the remaining €0.01 to the last installment

Comment: This would be a business question, not a programming question. Ask whoever you are working for how they want to handle it.

Comment: not sure who raised a close flag, but the question is pretty clear based on the response if nothing else

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a business logic/practices question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but I already knew the desired outcome (3.33,3.33,3.34) , so it was a programming question afterall, I was not asking what the desired outcome should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Bathsheba said, ask your users first.

Here's a technique that I've used often in such scenarios. This method will ensure the most even distribution, with the upward bias toward the end. For example, if you call `DivvyUp(101, 3)`, you'll get `33.66, 33.67, 33.67`. Notice that the difference isn't just made up for at the end. Instead, each value is computed according to what's left, not what was started with.

```
public static double[] DivvyUp(double total, uint count)
{
    var parts = new double[count];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        var part = Math.Truncate((100d * total) / (count - i)) / 100d;
        parts[i] = part;
        total -= part;
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any idea how to translate Math.Truncate to php ? (I need it there aswell , I have translated the rest but can't find Truncate)

Comment: Try `round` with the `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN` mode.

Answer (score 15):

You need to ask the accountant what they would want here. That's an important thing to do in software development: ask the users.

Normally, for stability, you would subtract the amounts paid from a balance account, and put checks in to ensure that the balance falls to zero.

And don't **ever** use a floating point data type when building accounting software. Floating point precision will bite you. Use a currency type instead.

Comment: This answer can't be upvoted enough. Accountants have their ways of solving those problems, you have to take this into account. They will not like any other solution (they also know the related laws).

Comment: +1, having worked writing integration with a few different accounting packages, it depends entirely on the software and users you are working for. Rounding methods in one accounting package may be alien and just plain wrong in others.

Comment: The user told he wanted it to be made into 3,33 , 3,33 , 3,34. So the other solutions work perfectly

Comment: Eric Evans devotes a great deal of his Domain Driven Design to solving this problem, but Bathsheba is correct.

Answer (score 11):

You could set the last by making up the difference, instead of via the same calculation as the rest. In pseudocode:

```
normalMonthPrice = RoundToTwoPlaces(totalPrice / months);
lastMonthPrice = totalPrice - (normalMonthPrice * (months - 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you've found out why the computing world isn't as simple as "put math on it"-

The easiest solution would be to divide by 3, round to two decimal places, and use that value for the first two months, and `original - 2 * perMonth` for the rest.