# Is there an algorithm that can divide a number into three parts and have their totals match the original number?

Tags: algorithm, oracle, plsql

For example if you take the following example into consideration.

```
100.00 - Original Number
33.33  - 1st divided by 3
33.33  - 2nd divided by 3
33.33  - 3rd divided by 3
99.99  - Is the sum of the 3 division outcomes

But i want it to match the original 100.00
```

One way that i saw it could be done was by taking the original number minus the first two divisions and the result would be my third number.  Now if i take those 3 numbers i get my original number.

```
 100.00 - Original Number
  33.33 - 1st divided by 3
  33.33 - 2nd divided by 3
  33.34 - 3rd number
 100.00 - Which gives me my original number correctly. (33.33+33.33+33.34 = 100.00)
```

Is there a formula for this either in Oracle PL/SQL or a function or something that could be implemented?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know of any such thing.  How would any library or function know which number to arbitrarily add the extra penny to?  Sounds like you've been struck by the "penny bug"

Comment: You may be interested in [Dividing prices by 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914074/dividing-prices-by-3), a recent similar question (albeit for c# instead of PL/SQL)

Comment: Didn't you just specify the "algorithm"? `N/3, N/3, N-2(N/3)`?

Comment: @Leeor yes i guess i did. I should have been a bit more specific that i was looking to do this in Oracle via some PL/SQL magic or analytical functions.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for the link i will take a look at that and see if it will translate to Oracle world.

Comment: Do you really not care that if the 3 parts are not equal?

Comment: I was presented with this exact problem in a budgetting system - they wanted to take an annual budget amount and divide it as evenly as possible between 12 months, with any rounding error applied to the 12th month.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp thats almost like my situation but i'm splitting a dollar amount I get in a quarter into 3 dollar amounts based on the months in that quarter. Where the total must equal the sum of the parts that were divided.

Comment: @user2025696, just for future reference, it would have been better if your question stated your actual requirements, along with matching sample data. Your sample output was misleading. But, thank you for the interesting question, it was fun :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This version takes precision as a parameter as well:

```
with q as (select 100 as val, 3 as parts, 2 as prec from dual)
select rownum as no
      ,case when rownum = parts
       then val - round(val / parts, prec) * (parts - 1) 
       else round(val / parts, prec)
       end v
from   q
connect by level <= parts

no  v
=== =====
1   33.33
2   33.33
3   33.34
```

For example, if you want to split the value among the number of days in the current month, you can do this:

```
with q as (select 100 as val
                 ,extract(day from last_day(sysdate)) as parts
                 ,2 as prec from dual)
select rownum as no
      ,case when rownum = parts
       then val - round(val / parts, prec) * (parts - 1) 
       else round(val / parts, prec)
       end v
from   q
connect by level <= parts;

1   3.33
2   3.33
3   3.33
4   3.33
...
27  3.33
28  3.33
29  3.33
30  3.43
```

To apportion the value amongst each month, weighted by the number of days in each month, you could do this instead (change the `level <= 3` to change the number of months it is calculated for):

```
with q as (
  select add_months(date '2013-07-01', rownum-1) the_month
        ,extract(day from last_day(add_months(date '2013-07-01', rownum-1)))
         as days_in_month
        ,100 as val
        ,2 as prec
  from dual
  connect by level <= 3)
,q2 as (
  select the_month, val, prec
        ,round(val * days_in_month 
                     / sum(days_in_month) over (), prec)
         as apportioned
        ,row_number() over (order by the_month desc) 
         as reverse_rn
  from   q)
select the_month
      ,case when reverse_rn = 1
       then val - sum(apportioned) over (order by the_month
                  rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
       else apportioned
       end as portion
from q2;

01/JUL/13   33.7
01/AUG/13   33.7
01/SEP/13   32.6
```

Comment: Jeffrey this looks very promising! I just had a follow-up.  What if the "parts" varied? Lets say something like "days in a month"? For example "(Value/TotalDays)*NumberOfDaysInMonth". Basically I would be breaking up the value into 3 months based on the number of days in that month.

Comment: No problem, just substitute the number of days into the query. You can use the LAST_DAY function to calculate the days in any month.

Comment: @user2025696 I rolled back your change because you were basically making a comment on this answer.  Please use the comments section for those types of questions / clarifications.  Editing the answer is for improving the existing content of it.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I tried adding the day count to your query. Basically changed the case to this `case when rownum = parts then val - round((val * (to_char(last_day(add_months(to_date('20130930', 'yyyymmdd'), -rownum)), 'dd')/ 92)), prec) * (parts - 1) 
 else round((val * (to_char(last_day(add_months(to_date('20130930', 'yyyymmdd'), -rownum)), 'dd'))/ 92), prec) end` ... But i get incorrect results for the last row. Is there something im missing?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp hi, would you be able to modify your example to include the number of months as the denominator instead of 'parts'? Like my previous comment shows? I guess i'm confused as to where to sub in the case above. thnx!

Comment: You need to put the number of parts (e.g. days in a month) in the parameters, don't substitute it into the query itself, otherwise it will be inconsistent - you are effectively using a different number of "parts" for each row in the output, so I'd expect the result to be incorrect. See my edit.

Comment: In your case you want to apportion the amount according to a weight, proportional to the number of days in the month. That's a bit trickier - working on it.

Answer (score 3):

[Use rational numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number). You could store the numbers as fractions rather than simple values. That's the only way to assure that the quantity is truly split in 3, and that it adds up to the original number. Sure you can do something hacky with rounding and remainders, as long as you don't care that the portions are not exactly split in 3.

The "algorithm" is simply that

100/3 + 100/3 + 100/3 == 300/3 == 100

Store both the numerator and the denominator in separate fields, then add the numerators. You can always convert to floating point when you display the values.

The [Oracle docs even have a nice example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a88896/dci05pls.htm) of how to implement it:

```
CREATE TYPE rational_type AS OBJECT
( numerator INTEGER,
  denominator INTEGER,
  MAP MEMBER FUNCTION rat_to_real RETURN REAL,
  MEMBER PROCEDURE normalize,
  MEMBER FUNCTION plus (x rational_type)
       RETURN rational_type);
```

Comment: Nice idea, until the user says "please report the number as a decimal number with 2 decimal digits - and the numbers must still add up to exactly 100" :)

Comment: The format used for reporting the values need not be the same format used for storing them. I suppose it might be useful to have some context for What this is being used for.

Comment: Agreed, depending on the actual requirement this may be the better answer - but the OP made their expected output quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a parameterized SQL version

```
  SELECT COUNT (*), grp
    FROM (WITH input AS (SELECT 100 p_number, 3 p_buckets FROM DUAL),
               data
               AS (    SELECT LEVEL id, (p_number / p_buckets) group_size
                         FROM input
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= p_number)
          SELECT id, CEIL (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY id) / group_size) grp
            FROM data)
GROUP BY grp
```

output:

```
COUNT(*)    GRP
33          1
33          2
34          3
```

If you edit the input parameters (p_number and p_buckets) the SQL essentially distributes p_number as evenly as possible among the # of buckets requested (p_buckets).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem yesterday by subtracting 2 of 3 parts from the starting number, e.g. 100 - 33.33 - 33.33 = 33.34 and the result of summing it up is still 100.

Comment: Pretty tricky. Now imagine that that there are 357 parts instead of 3. :)